# Asp.net tree view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, treeview, updatepanel

I have placed the TreeView in the update panel and HoverNodeStyle-Font-Underline="true"
when ever mouse hover underline will be shown.But after post back there is no underline when mouse over

Comment: Do you set the style programmatically or in the ASPX/ASCX?

Answer (score 1):

It can be a bit tricky to get the standard TreeView control to co-operate with ASP.NET Ajax - have a look at [this](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/hwo_to_create_an_aspnet_ajax_s.html) article by Matt Berseth.